# Pass phone number as destination of my message

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

Am trying to pass the phone number I picked from contact list of my device. I have edittext to write my message and then by one click I want to pick a number from the list and send at same time. Access phone number is confusing to me rather than access the name itself.( I don't need the name, i want to send my message to him/her as they have phone number.) I'm having **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid destinationAddress** for sms.sendTextMessage**

```
 public void Send(View view){
    String myMsg  = myMessage.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(no,null,myMsg,null,null);//"8044842795
}

    String no = "";

   @Override
     protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    if(reqCode == PICK_CONTACT) {
       if(resultCode == ActionBarActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();

           Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
           ContentResolver contect_resolver = getContentResolver();
           if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
               String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
               Cursor phoneCur = contect_resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

               if (phoneCur.moveToFirst()) {
                    no = phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
               }
           }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the SMS in onActivityResult.  Until that is called, you don't know who was chosen so you can't get their number.

Comment: This peace of code I didn't understand it.   Cursor phoneCur = contect_resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

Comment: THis is going to the contacts database and requesting all the data for the row with the id the user picked.  The next lines after that says if at least one result was found, get the phone number from that row (which may be null if you don't have the phone number in the contact).